# Application of validated logistic regression model on new data

Tags: logistic-regression

I have built a logistic regression algorithm in R and have trained it and tested it and now I want to apply it on new incoming data. My only question is that whether I always have to keep my training set data in the csv I want to get output of. If I am removing training set data, I am getting all values as NA

Comment: if you post your training code and prediction model here, I will help you learn to use it without the training data, but I need to see what you have.